# Chrome Packaged App AppWindow hide() and close() missing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Been experimenting with packaged apps using 23.0.1271.97, running into odd issues here and there.

Most recently, playing around with a multiple window app, I can create multiple windows fine, but the AppWindow object is missing the hide and close functions detailed in the [dev docs](https://developer.chrome.com/dev/apps/app.window.html#type-AppWindow).  Is there some other paradigm for this now that hasn't made its way into the docs?

Here's the console dump of an AppWindow object (with AppWindow and **proto** expanded):

```
appwinOptions
AppWindow
__proto__: Object
constructor: function () {}
contentWindow: Window
dom: Window
focus: function () { [native code] }
maximize: function () { [native code] }
minimize: function () { [native code] }
moveTo: function () { [native code] }
resizeTo: function () { [native code] }
restore: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Renato:

> AppWindow.close() and AppWindow.hide() methods are available in Chrome
>   Canary (25) and probably in dev too. If you are playing with Chrome
>   packaged app, please use Chrome Canary (preferably) or Dev. Current
>   stable (23) contains the very first version of packaged apps,
>   pre-developer preview, and many things have changed after that.

I've tested it in Canary, and they're working ok there.